# first selected checkbox should uncheck when user select 4th checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

User can select only 3 checkbox at a time.
If user selects the 4th checkbox then first checked (list checkbox) should unchecked. Meanwhile, if User selects 5th last selected (2nd) should deselect. I'm not able to create this logic.

```
      <script>
      var matches = [];
        var $checks = $('input:checkbox').click(function(e) {
         var numChecked = $checks.filter(':checked').length;
          var id=$(this).index();
           matches.push(id);
           alert(matches);
               if (numChecked > 3)
             {
               var new_no=matches[0];

                alert("sorry, you have already selected 3 checkboxes!");
                $('input:checkbox')[new_no].checked = false;
             }
        });


    </script>
```

Comment: Try creating a separate array that keeps track of which checkboxes have been checked and push/shift from that array.

Comment: And by 'first', do you mean first selected box on the page, or the first one according to the chronological order in which they were selected?

Comment: it sounds like you just need a queue, or?

Comment: i mean first one according to the chronological order in which they were selected

Answer (score 0):

You can add the selected options in a queue which can hold maximum of three elements. Once the number of elements exceeds the maximum limit just remove one from the queue.